# How to make Axios handle response data volume large than 1GB

Tags: javascript, axios

One of my responses data size may be larger than 1.5GB (Gzip size is just 31MB). After the data was downloaded totally I found the successful callback only got an empty string.

I can get the data once I reduce the records in the response, so it looks like a data volume issue. I cannot do anything about the backend code due to it belonging to a third party team.

Can I do something to make Axios able to handle this kind of volume data?